# coffee from seeds of dates

Tags: coffee, fruit, date-fruit

I once heard that it is possible to make coffee from seeds of dates.

I heard that you have to bake them in a low temperature.

So, I took seeds of dates, baked them in the oven in 100 degrees celsius for about an hour, and then tried to grind them.

The blades of the grinding machine broke.

Before I try again, I would like your seasoned advice: how can I make coffee from seeds of dates?

How can I know in advance that the seeds are soft enough for grinding?

Comment: 100 on what scale?  In either case, it isn't really hot enough toast  or roast them if that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: 100 celsius. How hot should it be?

Comment: I can't find any info on roasting date seeds, but coffee is usually roasted from about 200-250C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a video on making date seed coffee. Didn't come out very well though.

http://youtu.be/N5yCuLfZez4

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! My roasted date seeds also tasted like charcoal...

Comment: Aehm, link-only answers are nor exactly a good idea: what happens if the link goes bad? Could you please at least add the crucial points *in your answer*?

Answer (score 3):

[Handbook of Indices of Food Quality and Authenticity](http://books.google.com/books?id=gRSyiTDkxvYC&pg=PA474&lpg=PA474&dq=coffee%20substitute%20%22date%20seeds%22&source=bl&ots=p8X6ILCMVi&sig=RBFyB2Sxwu5jJTagdHUhStEoscA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4TEoU-SXMO2A2QXp1oHQDg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=coffee%20substitute%20%22date%20seeds%22&f=false) p474:

> The most important coffe substitute is undoubtedly chicory
>   ...
>   Chicory itself is reportedly adulterated by roasted beetroot
>   ...
>   Barley, malt, rye have been used...
>   Seeds which have been used include chickpeas, peanuts, soybeans, other beans
>   ...
>   Date seeds contain less extractives than coffee...

All are roasted somehow. 
[Coffee: Related Beverages](http://books.google.com/books?id=n9ZEMquvPoYC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=coffee%20substitute%20%22date%20seeds%22&source=bl&ots=qpEtCVsOfN&sig=NHqvvj2FXRdEyfUUqiRIfSW97mU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4TEoU-SXMO2A2QXp1oHQDg&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=coffee%20substitute%20%22date%20seeds%22&f=false) gives some roasting directions, but I don't immediately see a protocol for date seeds.

**Roasted** Kentucky Coffee Tree seeds are even still used occasionally.

If I wanted to grind date seeds, I'd smash them with a hammer first. Many seeds are unbelievably tough until broken.

Answer (score 2):

Date Seed Coffee is in deed a great coffee substitute - if you know how to make it :-)
It's nutritious and tasty.
However, if you 'roast' the date seed too fast you are likely to get exactly what you got namely charcoal - which is I guess good for Date Seed Barbecue Sauce :-)

You need to keep it on low fire for a very very very long time (until it turns earth brown) - towards the end give it a nice firing up. Use blades for dry food (shorter) and not liquid.

Alternatively, you could purchase Date Seed Coffee direct from on-line vendors such as http://dateseedcoffee.com

It is interesting to note that some do add a tiny amount of actual coffee to the Date Seed Coffee in order to give a note of the ground coffee we are all accustomed to.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail? "low fire for a very very very long time... towards the end give it a nice firing up" isn't nearly enough to allow anyone to reproduce the technique.